# Solve boolean algebra in assembly?

Tags: assembly, boolean-logic, x86-16, boolean-operations

I need to write a program to solve boolean expressions.

I have a string such as: '1+0*(1*0)'

How could I go about getting the result of this expression?

I'm thinking of changing it into postfix using the [Shunting-yard algorithm](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shunting-yard_algorithm) algorithm and then solving it but I don't know if it's necessary. Any ideas on how to do this will be appreciated.

Comment: Have you made any attempts at all to solving the problem you could share? What I've done in the passed to write an assembly function from scratch is write it in a language like C first, then hand assemble. It helps to break the problem down into pieces. Then you can hand-optimize the assembly.

Comment: @Liso22, in order to use Shunting-yard, your input must be in *infix*, not *postfix*.

Comment: sorry I meant converting from postfix to infix. Thanks for editing it. @mbratch: I haven't done it yet, for lack of a better option I'll have to use with the shunting-yard algorythm. What IDE does convert C to assembly? I have been using Codeblocks but I don't think it has that option

Comment: Many IDEs provide command line compile capability with an assembly output. I don't know what's available to you. But as I said in my prior comment, you can also do it by hand. You can write in any higher level language first, then hand compile to assembly. Writing in the higher level language first helps you structure your code and break the problem into sections so that writing the assembly is easier.

Comment: I like @isaach1000 idea of just using the native stack ability of the processor, since you're writing this in assembly. I would still recommend pseudocoding out the algorithm in more detail (almost a total lift from the published algorithm - with a few tweaks with your specifics), then start coding. You just need to dive in and play with it. You'll learn as you go. :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the equation is already in post-fix notation, you can solve it without the Shunting-Yard algorithm. For example, the above `1+0*(1*0)` would be `1 0 1 0 * * +`. Just push the elements onto a stack until you reach an operator, then pop 2 elements, and evaluate the result, pushing it back onto the stack.

In the example, `1`, `0`, `1`, and `0` get pushed onto the stack. Then `*` causes the stack to pop `0` and then `1`. The result is `0`. It is pushed onto the stack, which now contains `1`, `0`, `0` (order from bottom to top).  The `*` pops `0` and `0` from the stack, which results in `0`, which is pushed back onto the stack. Finally, `+` pops `0` and `0` from the stack, leaving the stack empty, and the result is 0.

This can be implemented in assembly quite easily because almost every CPU has a built in stack. Just read of the characters from the string and follow the steps above. You won't have to worry about parsing words because the operands/operators will not be longer than one character each.

Comment: thanks, my equation is in infix. Would it be a good idea to convert it to postfix and use your algorythm or would it be more practical to solve it in infix somehow?

Comment: btw could your algorythm handle negations eg: "1*!(1+0)"?

Comment: It would be a good idea to convert it or to use the shunting yard algorithm. The algorithm does work for negation, but you would only pop one number from the stack. The post-fix notation for your example would be `1 1 0 + ! *`, and the `!` operator would only pop one value, which in that case would be 1.

Comment: thanks, I implemented the shunting yard algorithm. I struggled a lot trying to solve the equation in infix and gave up, this way seems a lot easier.

Comment: does your implementation work with expressions like: 23/(23+67)-(67*5) etc. I mean operand with more than characters?

Comment: Yes it does. Store the digits as a string and then push it onto the stack when reaching an operator.